# Using multiprocessing to speed up a search

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to use python's multiprocessing (or some other python library) to speed up a search. I am using Python 3.4.2 currently. Here is how I have set up my searching and finding (my actual code is something otherwise, but the example code is an accurate stand in):

```
import random
def search():
    nums = list(range(1000))  # use a smaller range to test code
    random.shuffle(nums)
    if {1, 3, 13} - set(nums[:20]) == set(): # some random hard-coded search
        return nums
    return None

def find():
    res = None
    while res is None:
        res = search()
    return res

>>>find()
[56, 46, 71, 65, 47, 13, 96, 1, 3, 7, 16, 17, 28, ...
```

Needless to say, I could have written the search as a single function. Can I parallelize this search? That is, can I launch `search` on several processors and halt the searching once one of the processors returns a non `None` result? How do I do this? (Also, I don't have access to OpenMP, using Yosetime and all, and not wanting to install gcc).

(I have been trying to find a good tutorial, article etc. for help with this, so referencing any resources would be very helpful).

Comment: Are you trying to split the numbers in 0-1000 evenly among your processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of spawning a new process each time (which could get expensive), why not wrap the function body in a `while True`, and then kill the function when any process gives a useful result:

```
import random
import multiprocessing as mp

def search(qOut):
    while True:
        nums = list(range(1000))  # use a smaller range to test code
        random.shuffle(nums)
        if {1, 3, 13} - set(nums[:20]) == set(): # some random hard-coded search
            qOut.put(nums)

def find():
    q = mp.Queue()
    numProcs = mp.cpu_count() -1  # one per processor
    procs = [mp.Process(target=search, args=(q,) for _ in range(numProcs)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()

    res = q.get()
    print("Got a result")

    for p in procs:
        p.terminate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward code example, and the explanation about how to structure the code for search.